# Change in standard in assignment operation

Tags: c++, c++11

Can someone explain what was changed about the following in new standard with an example? Does this refer to strict aliasing rules?

> 5.17/8. If the value being stored in an object is accessed from another object that overlaps in any way the storage of the first
>   object, then the overlap shall be exact and the two objects shall have
>   the same type, otherwise the behavior is undefined.

In the new standard, it was changed with following note:

> [ Note: This restriction applies to the relationship between the left
>   and right sides of the assignment operation; it is not a statement
>   about how the target of the assignment may be aliased in general. See
>   3.10. — end note ]

Answer (score 2):

This explains the change: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#556

> There appear to be two different specifications for when aliasing is permitted.
>
> [...]
>
> This issue is based on a misunderstanding of the intent of the wording in 5.17 [expr.ass] paragraph 8. Instead of being a general statement about aliasing, it's describing the situation in which the source of the value being assigned is storage that overlaps the storage of the target object. The proposed resolution should make that clearer rather than changing the specification.